# range(len(word) - 2) in Words with three consecutive letters

Tags: python

The assignment is to implement the `words_consecutive_letters` function. It takes as input the name of a file with words (one word per line). It returns a list with words that contain three consecutive letters of the alphabet. In the answer I've seen that they used **range(len(word)-2)**. My question is why do they use -2 in this answer instead of range(len(word)), why not the full range of the length of the word? The answer is the following:

```
def words_consecutive_letters(filename: str) -> list[str]:
"""Returns a list of all words that contain three consecutive letters of 
the alphabet, as found in the file with the given name.
"""
  res = []
  with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        for i in range(len(word) - 2):
            # Convert the letters using ord and compare them.
            if ord(word[i]) + 1 == ord(word[i+1]) and ord(word[i+1]) + 1 == ord(word[i+2]):
                res.append(word)
                break

   return res
```

Comment: Because the second last and last letters in the word cannot be part of 3 consecutive letters of the alphabet given there arent enough letters following them

Comment: You would get an index error on trying word[i+1] and word[i+2] if you went all the way to range(len(word))

Comment: Practically `word[i+2]` would throw an error otherwise, as it would try accessing characters of `word` beyond its end. (`word[i+1]` too, just i+2 gets out of bound one step sooner)